# Organization could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

Today I'm facing an issue when want to share the transit gateway to a specific organization with error message below: `Organization o-abcdefghq could not be found. (Service: AWSRAM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnknownResourceException; Request ID: 70749448-e9101-48c2-918d-c8b40eq1aa32; Proxy: null)`

Is anyone able to help me, please? thank you

Transit gateway is able to share within organization

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now solved with the following steps:

1. Login to your master AWS account as root user
2. Go to the Organizations console and click 'Settings'
3. 'Disable Access' for AWS Resource Access Manager from the 'Trusted access for AWS services' tab
4. Go to the RAM console, and Click on Settings.
5. Select  “Enable sharing within your AWS Organization”.
6. Create the resource share again, remember uncheck "Allow external accounts" option, put the account ID again-->Save.

Comment: Did you find out _why_ this was happening?

Comment: You can skip steps 2 and 3. Checking the box in step 5 automatically does step 3.